SBQQ CPQ - To throw an validation when two configuration attributes are same
I am trying to implement a validation rule that triggers on Save in the Configurator screen. I have two Configuration Attributes (Origin and Destination). When both values are the same, I want to display a validation error stating that the origin and destination cannot be the same.

What I’ve Tried So Far:
Set Configuration Attributes to Apply Immediately:
I configured the attributes (Origin and Destination) to apply immediately to the product options.
Use a Price Rule on Edit:
I created a price rule that sets a checkbox on the product options to true when the Origin and Destination fields on the product options are the same. This relies on configuration attributes being applied to product options immediately as described in step 1.
Create a Product Rule for Validation:
I added a product rule to display a validation error when the checkbox (set in step 2) is marked as true.
However, this approach is not working as expected.
